# Spring kafka 2.3.1 not supported in spring boot V2.1.9.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have spring boot application up which uses spring boot V2.1.9.RELEASE Version. I want to upgrade only spring Kafka. But after upgraded I got no such method found errors.

i tried to upgrade spring boot to 2.2.0  but due to some other plugins like swagger are not supported in this.

Logs:

```
2019-10-30 14:35:36.236  WARN [xxxxx-component-workflow-handler,,,] 20192 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
2019-10-30 14:35:36.256  INFO [xxxxx-component-workflow-handler,,,] 20192 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-30 14:35:36.268 ERROR [xxxxx-component-workflow-handler,,,] 20192 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
    at com.xxxxx.business.workflow.component.handler.ComponentWorkflowHandlerApplication.main(ComponentWorkflowHandlerApplication.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<init>(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:141)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

can we use spring Kafka with older spring boot versions..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

spring-kafka 2.3.x requires Spring Framework 5.2 and will only work with Boot 2.2.x.